# Accessible gas pipe union

Tags: plumbing, pipe, gas

I have an 8x8 opening in a wall with a small panel door and currently it holds the supply gas pipe valve for the house. The pipe then exits the wall and becomes exposed in a room. I would like to make the room part semi modular so that I can detach it easily on one end so I can remove if need to (for painting etc.)

[image]

Where you see a tee, I would like to put a reusable union so that I can untwist it there and the other end (2nd picture) can be removed with a wrench.

[image]

Is it okay (by the code and/or best practice) to have a reusable union for gas pipe, which can be dangerous if loose/leaking, behind a service panel entrance?

Answer (score 1):

Unions are not allowed behind walls. If your wall is removable then it is more like furniture or painting. For example. A screwed on panel for a furnace room door is okay. There is a union at the furnace. So it is okay.

Comment: is a service panel entrance considered a closed wall ?

Comment: No- that's why it's a service panel. You put a service panel in to be able to access things that can't be behind a closed wall.